# KML (with no data/feature) to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, convert, kml

I have a .kml file and it opens on my Google Earth Pro. When I tried converting it through ArcMap it didn't work, an error occurred saying it had no data. On further googling about it, I understand that there are 2 types of .kml files. One which has data or feature and the other has a basically a link to the actual file that has the data. Since I have the old one, I need to know how to I convert it into shapefile.

The software(s) I have are ArcMap, QGIS 3, and Erdas Imagine.

Comment: What happens when you try to open your KML with QGIS?

Comment: Your title says kml with no data/feature, but then you say you have "the former one," which is a kml with no data, only a link to data. So which kind of kml do you have?

Comment: KML files can be loaded as vector layers in QGIS. There is no need to convert in order to load the data into the map view. I second @GBG with his question as to what happens if you load the KML file in QGIS? You can also open your KML file in a text editor (Notepad++) and view its contents. There you can be sure it's not just pointing to some data source.

Comment: You can view the KML to make sure it shows up or not... http://kmlviewer.nsspot.net/